# Command to spawn vscode terminal from another vscode terminal

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a terminal command to spawn a new terminal from an existing vscode terminal.

In my case I want to craft a command that runs a front-end server in one terminal and a backend server in another.

Hope that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Makes total sense, want to do the same. DId you find the solution?

Comment: Not yet.. I'd still love to figure this out