# How to clone a terminal in vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am using the java debugger and the java projects extension on vscode and I need to compile my project two times using the java process console which pops out when I choose the 'play' icon from the gui next to my project name (in java projects extension tab in the integrated explorer). The problem is that when the server of my application is running and I choose to compile and run the Client side from that same icon, nothing really happens because the java process console is already busy running the Server. So my question is: 
**How to open an additional java process console?**
Is there any special command that I can run to launch another java process console after I split the first one? 
*NOTE* My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47362465/command-to-spawn-vscode-terminal-from-another-vscode-terminal) one but since there was no activity there, I opened a new one. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I cannot even open the project at two separate vscode windows at the same time, the moment I choose to open my existing project I am being redirected to the first existing vscode window.

Comment: how about using different shell? like using cmd in current window, and powershell in another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MollyWang Thank you for your interest, but I am satisfied with a workaround I was told to try out.The command that is going to run a certain executable while taking into consideration all the classes of the java project is produced by the vscode gui and printed in the terminal (Java Proccess console).Then I copy it, open another cmd and change the file I want to be run. All of that because, vscode cannot have to Java consoles opened at the same time. Once you try to run your Client program at a new console , you will be prompted to the first one you created and you will miss the execution of your Server.class.

So if you are using the VsCode Java Projects extension and reading this, don't waste any time trying to clone the terminal the extension creates for you.
It simply cannot be done.Hope that helped.